# vold.fstab file in Android 4.3

Tags: android, linux

I want to get the external and internal storage in my app. I'm using this code

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/etc/vold.fstab"));

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if (line.toLowerCase().contains("dev_mount")) {
                    if (line.toLowerCase().contains("nonremovable")) {
                        VoldMounts.put(line.split(" ")[2],true);
                    }else {
                        VoldMounts.put(line.split(" ")[2],false);
                    }
                }
            }
```

It's working fine on Android 4.2.2 and below, but on Android 4.3 the file is changed to `/fstab.<device>` and this file needs root access. How can I read the fstab without the need of root access? I don't want to use /proc/mount.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain **completely and precisely** what "it is not working" means.

Comment: It seems like the `/fstab.<device>` file is already present on pre-4.3 devices which still have `/etc/vold.stab`, so the frist does not seem to have replaced the latter file.

Comment: However, according to [this post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=45453699&postcount=10), the two files have been unified.

Comment: according to the post i have to get root access, iam developing an app, and i dont want the user to get root privileges, so can i read the {/fstab.<device>} without the rneed of root access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/storage/) is some official information that confirms that "for Android releases 4.3 and later, the various fstab files used by init, vold and recovery were unified in the /fstab. file". As that file has `-rw-r----- root     root` permissions there is no way to read it from an app on a non-rooted device.